# Apply XSL to RSS Feed

Tags: xslt, rss

I want to display an RSS feed from Feedburner on my website, however I'd like to be able to apply an XSLT to it as well.

Is it possible to fetch a URL in an XSLT rather than add the link to the style in the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load an external xml file in your stylesheet using the [document](http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/func_document.asp) function.

(Edited after the comment)

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document("myurl.xml")/root" mode="extern"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root" mode="extern">
Hello world
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you offer an example of how to use it to fetch a url?